# UWP Template 10 show busy indicator

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Im trying to activate the busy indicator in my windows 10 app with Template 10 as base. what i tried:

```
Shell view = (Shell)Window.Current.Content;
view.SetBusyIndicator(Visibility.Visible);
// Do something
view.SetBusyIndicator(Visibility.Collapsed);
```

This works but after collapsing the busy indicator the hamburger menu isn't working anymore. I can open the hamburger menu, but i can't navigate anymore.

So how ca i activate en deactivate the busy indicator?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is SetBusyIndicator coming from? It's not in the current code of Template10, so maybe you're using some old code of the project? Try having a look at the current Template10 Minimal project, as it works properly there: https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/a5fa37b6ce6c28c76b50fc64f85414b74a11156b/Templates%20(Project)/Minimal/ViewModels/SettingsPageViewModel.cs#L43

Comment: Yes, that worked! thanks :)

Comment: Well i thought it worked. But when i set IsBusy to false, the loading screen stays active.

Comment: What's the code you're using there? Are you getting the same Shell object at each call? It's hard to tell without code because the minimal project obviously works for lots of people, including me. So there's no general answer to your question ;)

Comment: I don't know how but it's all working now :) Thanks!

Comment: What's working? There is no SetBusyIndicator lol